# Last iteration of for each loop won't update the row count

Tags: c#, excel, foreach, datatable

My issue is coming from the for each loop's last execution, as I think when it removes a row it doesn't correctly update. When I read through all the rows/columns if I find any that have special characters it is removed, for some reason on the last iteration it does not update the row count and instead gives me a duplicate row.

(Example output)
Row 1 issues found
Row 2 issues found
Row 2 issues found (this should actually be Row 3 but again it doesn't update correctly and displays Row 2 to the user, I want them to be able to go into the excel sheet and find out if the row was actually a problem or not and when I have bigger datasets being exported the numbers get even higher and more confusing)

I also want to mention in case it's important that this is a method and is used for a button click

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath).Replace("\"", "").Replace("\r", "");

    //Check if the data contains the headings if it does we remove it
    if (csvData.Contains(headings))
    {
        csvData = (csvData.Remove(csvData.IndexOf(headings), headings.Length));
    }
  
    foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();

            int i = 0;
         
            foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
            {

                // Column 1 First Name
                if (CheckSpecialCharacters(cell) && i == 0)
                {
                    Message_Label.Text += "Row " + removeRowCount + " Col " + (i + 1) + " (First Name) - Issues Detected & Removed!<br/>";
                    removeRow = true;
                }

                //// Column 2 Last Name
                if (CheckSpecialCharacters(cell) && i == 1)
                {
                    Message_Label.Text += "Row " + dt.Rows.Count + " Col " + (i + 1) + "(Last Name) - Issues Detected & Removed!<br/>";
                    removeRow = true;
                }

                //Column 3  (EMAIL)
                if (!isValidEmail(cell) && i == 2)
                {   
                    Message_Label.Text += "Row " + dt.Rows.Count + " Col " + (i + 1) + " - (Email) Issues Detected & Removed!<br/>";
                    removeRow = true;
                }
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                i++;
         
            }
            //If removeRow returns true remove the last item
            if (removeRow == true)
            {  
               dt.Rows.RemoveAt(dt.Rows.Count -1);
            }          
        }     
    }
```

I have tried adding an additional row to offset the removing and it works, but the problem with that is it adds additional rows all with NULL values in them which is clogging the DB with blank space. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: if you are removing row do not use foreach, instead use inverse for loop like for(int i  = dgv.rows.count, i <= 0, i--)

Comment: And if you want to use foreach loop then do not remove rows within the foreach loop just get some unique identification of the rows that you want to remove and store it in new list and use that new list to remove rows from data grid

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thank you for your second suggestion it's working like a charm! I'm new to this how do I mark your reply as the answer?

Comment: No need, happy that your problem is solved.